# The IDictionary of a Exception.Data property keep the order always?

Tags: c#, exception

I know that a Dictionary doesn't ensure that the order of the elements when are added is keeping, I mean, that after adding many items in the dictionary, if it is tried to get an element with the elementAt(i) method, It can return an expected element.

[Exception.Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data(v=vs.110).aspx) is an IDictionary, so I was wondering if this is true in this case, because in the documentation on MSDN, they use a foreach to iterate over this property to show the information, so I guess that the order is keeping in this case.

So in the case of the Exception.Data, the order of the elements that are adding is keeping?

Comment: An `IDictionary` doesn't guarantee any ordering, but an implementation of `IDictionary` may do so.   As far as I can see the implementation in .NET 4.x is an internal class ListDictionaryInternal, which as far as I can see uses a linked list which does preserve order.  Nevertheless, in the absence of documentation guaranteeing this behavior, it would be unwise to rely on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... if this:

```
//      Extra details:
//        Key: 'stringInfo'              Value: Information from NestedRoutine2.
//        Key: 'IntInfo'                 Value: -903
//        Key: 'DateTimeInfo'            Value: 7/29/2013 10:50:13 AM
//        Key: 'ExtraInfo'               Value: Information from NestedRoutine1.
//        Key: 'MoreExtraInfo'           Value: More information from NestedRoutine1.
```

is the list of all the Key's that the Exception.Data contains, then why would it be matter if they are in order, when you can just do something like this:

```
string[] exceptionList = { "stringInfo", "IntInfo", "DateTimeInfo", "ExtraInfo", "MoreExtraInfo" };
foreach ( string exceptionName in exceptionList ) {
  if ( myData.Exception.Data.ContainsKey(exceptionname) ) {
    // do something with that exception key/value pair
  }
}
```